# Ajax update post request on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I would like to click on a previous or next button and update the ajax post request.  The parameter I want to change is the variable called "page".  The URL of the request takes this variable to show the right page.  When I click on a previous or next button I want to change the "page" variable value. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{

var pageSize = "pageSize=10";
//want to change the page number on click
var page = "page=1"

var requestIndex = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `url`,
    beforeSend: function(){
     $("#loading").show();
   },
   complete: function(){
     $("#loading").hide();
   }
});
// console.log(request)
requestIndex.done((data)=>{
  var done = JSON.parse(data)

    //  console.log(done)
    done.forEach((result, index)=>{
    //  res.push(result)
    var firstName = result.FirstName;
    var lastName = result.LastName;
    var modelYear = result.ModelYear;
    var make = result.Make;
    var model = result.Model;
    var dealership = result.Dealership;

      $('#test>tbody').append(`
          <tr>
            <td>${firstName} ${lastName}</td>
            <td>${modelYear}</td>
            <td>${make}</td>
            <td>${model}</td>
            <td>${dealership}</td>
          </tr>
      `)  
  
    })
    var tr = $('table').find("tr");
    var resultQuant =[]
    resultQuant.push(tr)
    var pages = []
      
      //loop over each result and create pagination
      resultQuant.forEach(function(res, index){
        console.log(res.length);
        if(res.length > 9){
          $('#prev_page').append(`
            Prev Page
          `)
          $('#next_page').append(`
            Next Page
          `)
        }
      })    
    });

    requestIndex.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          console.log('failed')
    });

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working snippet for what I think you're looking for. I had to make some changes, some for aesthetics, and some for functionality. Here's the functional changes/updates:

- Your whole ajax/refresh table script needed to be outsourced to a function so it could be called multiple times.
- The page and pageSize variables are better left as numbers rather than queryString strings
- I created a delegated event listener on your buttons. It's one listener that will handle either button. The listener callback finds out if its the next or previous button that was clicked, then calls the `goToPage()` function with the incremented `onPage` variable
- The table is now cleared before each new data batch is written to it, as you'd expect a paginated result to be
- The buttons should disable/enable according to the pagination, so I put in a script to test if we're at the first page or the last page to disable/enable them
- I changed all your `var`s to `let`s because that's the way we initialize block variables nowadays

```js
let onPage, pageSize = 10;
$(document).ready(() => {
  goToPage(1)
  $('body').on('click', '#next_page, #prev_page', function() {
    inc = 1;
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'prev_page') inc = -1;
    goToPage(onPage + inc);
  })
})

function goToPage(page) {
  let requestIndex = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `url`,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function() {
      $("#loading").hide();
    }
  });
  requestIndex.done((data) => {
    onPage = page;
    $('#test>tbody').html('');
    JSON.parse(data).forEach((result, index) => {
      $('#test>tbody').append(`
          <tr>
            <td>${result.FirstName} ${result.LastName}</td>
            <td>${result.ModelYear}</td>
            <td>${result.Make}</td>
            <td>${result.Model}</td>
            <td>${result.Dealership}</td>
          </tr>
      `)
    })
    if (onPage > 1) $('#prev_page').removeAttr('disabled');
    else $('#prev_page').attr('disabled', true)

    if (JSON.parse(data).length === pageSize) $('#next_page').removeAttr('disabled');
    else $('#next_page').attr('disabled', true)
  });

  requestIndex.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log('failed')
  });
}
```

```css
#loading {
  display: none'

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='loading'>Loading...</div>
<table id='test'>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button id='prev_page'>Prev Page</button>
<button id='next_page'>Next Page</button>
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I just had a quick question.  What does goToPage(1) mean?  It looks like a function call assigning a call back but I'm not sure.

Comment: `goToPage(1)` is just calling the function `goToPage()`, sending the page parameter in it. It is in `document.ready()` to get things started